# Notification Long Press Options Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

When you long press a Notification in Android, you get something like what is pictured. The settings icon (Circled) doesn't normally appear. How do you add options like that settings icon?
 [image: Long press options]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eli, I think you would do something like this:

```
down.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But of course, I could of told you by texting, but this is funnier.